# Protocol Buffers 3 partial update

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am trying to implement partial update with Protocol Buffers 3 (using Go). The problem is that in some cases it's not possible to distinguish default (empty) values and the same values set on purpose (like a description set to an empty string to clear it).

After some digging I found reference to [FieldMasks](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#fieldmask) in [this](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/225) issue which explains that such values cannot be distinguished, but an incremental update is possible using FieldMasks.

I tried to find some documentation or guide explaining how to use FieldMasks, but I couldn't.

So the question is: how can I achieve partial update with proto3 (using FieldMasks)?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In proto3, there is no difference between an unset variable and a null/empty variable, and hence, I use a default value with every field (in a constructor/builder) and check for that instead.